# Display Records which match user input

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, parsing

I am creating a simple application in C# WPF that reads and writes data to a csv file. I want to only display records within the CSV file where the username entered by the user matches the value at [0].

The code I have for this so far is following:

```
private void ViewSightings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //take user input for their username
            string username = inputUsername.Text;

            Wishlist wishlist = new Wishlist(); //create new instance of wishlist
            string[] WishlistArray; //create wishlist array
            var wishlists = new List<string[]>(); //create list

            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //new instance of datatable
            //add column headers to the datatable for wishlist 
            dt.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Colour", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Sex", typeof(string));

            //read in the wishlists file
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    WishlistArray = reader.ReadLine().Split(','); //split with a comma

                    foreach (var wish in wishlists) //iterate through lines
                    {

                        if (WishlistArray[0] == username)
                        {
                            wishlist.Username = WishlistArray[0];
                            wishlist.Type = WishlistArray[1];
                            wishlist.Category = WishlistArray[2];
                            wishlist.Colour = WishlistArray[3];
                            wishlist.Size = WishlistArray[4];
                            wishlist.Sex = WishlistArray[5];

                        }
                        
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(WishlistArray); //add data to wishlist array

                    DataView dv = new DataView(dt); //input data into datatable
                    dgWishlists.ItemsSource = dv; //display data in datatable
                }
                //close the popup
                EnterUsernamePopup.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
```

I have done some research and have implemented where the WishlistArray[0] == username but this is continuing to display all records in my CSV file regardless of what the username is.

Is anyone able to help me with what I am doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

you are adding wishlistarray to dt regardless of whether the username matches or not

try:

```
private void ViewSightings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //take user input for their username
            string username = inputUsername.Text;

            Wishlist wishlist = new Wishlist(); //create new instance of wishlist
            string[] WishlistArray; //create wishlist array
            var wishlists = new List<string[]>(); //create list

            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //new instance of datatable
            //add column headers to the datatable for wishlist 
            dt.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Colour", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Sex", typeof(string));

            //read in the wishlists file
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    WishlistArray = reader.ReadLine().Split(','); //split with a comma

                    foreach (var wish in wishlists) //iterate through lines
                    {

                        if (WishlistArray[0] == username)
                        {
                             dt.Rows.Add(WishlistArray); //add data to wishlist array                        
                        }
                        
                    }


                    DataView dv = new DataView(dt); //input data into datatable
                    dgWishlists.ItemsSource = dv; //display data in datatable
                }
                //close the popup
                EnterUsernamePopup.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
```